# An integral of a differential equation that's troubling me

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, integrating-factor

I am facing a problem in differential equations.

$$(x-x^3)dy = (y+yx^2-3x^4)dx\tag{Question}$$

I am completely recognisant that I can use the linear differential equation form here, as I have shown below:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+yx^2-3x^4}{x-x^3}=y\frac{1+x^2}{x-x^3}-\frac{3x^3}{1-x^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-y\frac{1+x^2}{x-x^3}=-\frac{3x^3}{1-x^2}$$

From the above LDE form, I can deduce the below

$$Integrating\space factor = e^{-\int\frac{(1+x^2)}{x-x^3} \,dx}\tag{Problematic one}$$

Now I tried catching WolframAlpha (I did not know how to proceed, but eventually I recognized the partial fraction present), and it gave me the answer for the integrating factor as $$\frac{1-x^2}{x}$$ This would further complicate things as the final solution would look like:

$$y\times\frac{1-x^2}{x}=-\int\frac{3x^3}{1-x^2}\times\frac{1-x^2}{x}dx\tag{Problematic one}$$

which makes it an excessively lengthy problem.

---

This problem is from the JEE Mains 2021 where barely 3 minutes is given for a problem and this would be quite solvable if and only if Physics and Chemistry were over in an hour or so.

I am a 12th grader where we learn only substitution, partial fractions and integration by parts here.

Any suggestions for alternative methods to do this faster?

---

EDIT:
After the complete error rectification now the problem seems fine. I will be able to proceed.

Comment: That integral is handled by long division, then partial fractions if needed.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I am looking for alternatives, the method I followed is excessively lengthy. Long division, then again partial fractions only lengthens the problem

Comment: On correcting the error, I get the form now, so I'll upload my answer soon.

Comment: It's off-topic now, but the "problematic" integral can be simplified a bit by replacing $x^2=\dfrac{1+y}{1-y}$ to get$$\int\frac{dy}{y-y^3}$$Still some partial fractions to deal with, and you trade polynomial division for simplifying a nested rational expression.

Comment: @user170231 I getcha.

Comment: **All comments given above are for the older version of the post.**

Comment: I am closing this question because the situation here has become hopelessly muddled.  The original version of this question, which was answered by several people, apparently contained an error.  The edited version of this question invalidates the answers already given.  This is poor practice---if you note an error in a question *after* it has been answered, *do not* edit the question so that it invalidates existing answers.  Ask a new question.

Comment: Understood @XanderHenderson. Sorry for all the trouble btw :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are given

$$(x-x^3)dy = (y-yx^2-3x^4)dx$$

We can write this as

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-yx^2-3x^4}{x-x^3}=y\dfrac{1-x^2}{x-x^3}-\dfrac{3x^3}{1-x^2}$$

You seem to have a simple algebra issue, it is $1-x^2$, not $1+x^2$.

You should have gotten $$\dfrac{1-x^2}{x-x^3} = \dfrac{1}{x}$$

The integral and exponential are easy now.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation as
$$
\frac{d y}{d x}+\frac{y\left(1+x^2\right)}{x\left(x^2-1\right)}=\frac{3 x^3}{x^2-1} \tag*{(*)} 
$$
Then the integrating factor is
$$ e^{\int \frac{2 x+1}{x(x+1)} d x} =e^{\ln \left(\frac{1-x^2}{x}\right)} =\frac{1-x^2}{x}
$$
Multiplying the equation $(*)$ by $\frac{1-x^2}{x}$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1-x^2}{x} \frac{d y}{d x}-\frac{\left(1+x^2\right) y}{x^2}&=-3 x^2 \\
\frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{x} y\right)&=-3 x^2 \\
\frac{1-x^2}{x} y&=-x^3+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence the solution of the differential equation is
$$
y=\frac{Cx}{1-x^2}+\frac{x^4}{x^2-1}
$$
where $C$ is a constant.